# Marvel Comics titles Annihilation and Annihilation: Conquest, which came first?

Tags: comics, marvel, suggested-order

I'm interested in reading the Marvel *Annihilation* stories/arcs. What I don't know is what order to read them in. From what I can tell, there is the main *Annihilation* series and companion issues like *Annihilation: Nova*, *Annihilation: Starlord*, *Annihilation: Wraith*, etc. (I've seen a handful of different character titles.)

In addition, I've seen an *Annihilation: Conquest* title as well. I assume all these titles involve characters in the *Guardians of the Galaxy* team. Is that correct?

Furthermore, I'm interested in reading the standalone *Nova* series but would like to know how the aforementioned titles sort into that.

Answer (score 4):

### Annihilation: Prologue

A 48-page one-shot issue, *Annihilation: Prologue*, was released on March 15, 2006.

It was followed by four concurrent 4-issue mini-series:

- Silver Surfer (April 1, 2006),
- Super-Skrull (April 12, 2006),
- Nova (April 19, 2006), and
- Ronan the Accuser (April 26, 2006).

*Annihilation* was published as a six issue mini series beginning in August 2006.

It was followed by two issues of *Annihilation: Heralds of Galactus* and a new volume of *Nova*.

While not published with the Annihilation banner,

- Drax the Destroyer: Earth Fall #1-4 (Sept 2005) and
- Thanos #7-12 (2004) were preludes to the event.

### Annihilation: Conquest

**Volume One** 
(collects "Annihilation: Conquest - Prologue" one-shot, Annihilation: Conquest - Quasar mini-series, Annihilation: Conquest - Starlord mini-series and "Annihilation: Saga" one-shot, 272 pages, Marvel Comics, hardcover, January 2008, ISBN 0-7851-2782-8, softcover, November 2008, ISBN 0-7851-2783-6)

**Volume Two** 
(collects *Annihilation: Conquest - Wraith* mini-series, *Nova* #4-7 and *Annihilation: Conquest limited series*, 344 pages, Marvel Comics, hardcover, August 2008, ISBN 0-7851-2716-X, softcover, February 2009, ISBN 0-7851-2717-8)

Some of series involved have been collected in separate softcover releases:

*Annihilation: Conquest - Quasar* (by Christos Gage and Mike Lilly, collects 4-issue mini-series, January 2008, 96 pages, ISBN 0-7851-2718-6)

*Nova Volume 1: Annihilation - Conquest* (by Dan Abnett/Andy Lanning, with art by Sean Chen, collects Nova #1-7, 168 pages, December 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2631-7)